# Create Polybase tables from DataBricks

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-synapse, polybase, azure-data-lake-gen2

Being new to Datawarehouse, I have a new requirement to create EXTERNAL TABLE from Datalake(GEN1/GEN2) into DWH from Databricks. I used the [link](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/sql-data-warehouse.html) to create the below code.

```
// Set up the Blob storage account access key in the notebook session conf.
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  "<your-storage-account-access-key>")

// Get some data from a SQL DW table.
val df: DataFrame = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<the-rest-of-the-connection-string>")
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>")
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
  .option("dbTable", "my_table_in_dw")
  .load()
```

The code that I have written

```
%scala

Class.forName("com.databricks.spark.sqldw.DefaultSource")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SQLContext}


spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.xxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

    // Load data from a SQL DW query
   val df: DataFrame = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net:1433;database=xxxxxxxx")
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net")
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
  .option("dbTable", "dbo.EXT_TEST") 
  .load()
```

This is throwing an error : 
com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDWConnectorException: Exception encountered in SQL DW connector code.
Where am I going wrong? Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to pass the "tempDir" as shown in the below format.

```
tempDir = "wasbs://" + blobContainer + "@" + blobStorage +"/tempDirs"
```

**Reference:** [Load data into Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/databricks-extract-load-sql-data-warehouse#load-data-into-azure-sql-data-warehouse)

You may refer the suggestions outlined on [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/12263) issue, which addresses similar issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.